# Is there a way to know which columns have different datatypes to be able to merge? Python - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, valueerror

So I have 2 pretty large df's and I got some ValueErrors.

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

I checked them one by one(30 columns, oof) and ended up solving the issue, but I wounder if there is any code that can give me the specific column(s) that are preventing the merge... it could be very usefull to me since I am working on other people's dataframes and stuff like this happens all the time.

Example:

```
df1 (4.000.000,30) df2 (2.000,120)


Join= pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',on['Name_of_Column1','Name_of_Column2','Name_of_Column3','Name_of_Column4'])
```

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

They have only some of the columns in common, can I compare the dtypes of the dfs somehow to know what columns have different dtypes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're looking for but [df.dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) seems a good place to start. If you [edit] to include a [mcve] we might be able to provide more specific help

Comment: You need to provide some sample data in order to get the answers for your query.

Comment: I tried making it a bit clearer.  I copied df.dtype to an excel and figgured it out, but would there be a way to compare them in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 data frames with similar column names, and are only interested in knowing which columns don't have the same `dtype` across both data frames so that you do a merge in peace, you could try the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,'3',4],
                   [1,2,'3',4],
                   [1,2,'3',4]], columns=['a','b','c','d'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5,5,'5','5'],
                   [5,5,'5','5'],
                   [5,5,'5','5']], columns=['a','b','c','d'])
```

Taking these 2 data frames where the `'d'` column has a `dtype` mismatch

```
def dtype_checker(df1, df2):
    df1_types = dict(df1.dtypes)
    df2_types = dict(df2.dtypes)
    for col_name in df1.columns:
        assert df1_types[col_name] == df2_types[col_name], 'dtype mismatch in '+col_name+' column'

dtype_checker(df1, df2)
```

Which will result in the output:

```
AssertionError: dtype mismatch in d column
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted